# Unable to pass data from MainActivity to RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: java, android

i try to show text in a Recyclerview.
Therefore i parse JsonData into a ArrayList>
after i got this content im calling the following Method:

```
 private void loadprevEvents() {
    for (HashMap<String, String> data :datalist){
        items_for_preview.addString(data.get("names"));
        items_for_preview.addString("imageurl");
    }
   Customlist adapter = new Customlist_upcoming_events(items_for_preview,getApplicationContext());

}
```

Unfortunately here is my Problem because i try to save the Data in a List called items_for_preview.
But i cant save the Strings into this List.
My app says:
Cannot resolve "getString"
Here is my Getter_Setter_Events_Prev class:

```
String date;
String imageUrl;
String name;

public Getter_Setter_Events_Prev(String date, String imageUrl, String name) {
    this.date = date;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

and here is my Adapter Class:

```
public class Customlist_upcoming_events extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Customlist_upcoming_events.ViewHolder> {
private List<Getter_Setter_Events_Prev> items;
private Context context;

public Customlist_upcoming_events(List<Getter_Setter_Events_Prev> items, Context context) {
    this.items = items;
    this.context = context;
}



@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.model_upcoming_events, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Getter_Setter_Events_Prev gt = items.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(gt.getName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView name;
    public ImageView pic;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.prev_events_name);
        pic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_thumb);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What's the type of `items_for_preview` list?

Comment: Yes it's List<Getter_Setter_Events_prev>

Comment: There's no `addString` method for `java.util.List` interface. Only `add(T t)`.

Comment: And how should I send the data to my adapter ?

Comment: In your case you should add instances of `Getter_Setter_Events_Prev`. Create an instance and use `items_for_preview.add(Getter_Setter_Events_Prev instance)`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand could you explain it in detail

Comment: I have to pass my arraylist to the adapter and should get the position